# How do I distinguish between Python single-line and multi-line strings in Vim syntax?

Tags: python, vim

I just discovered the crazy awesome Vim plugin [OnSyntaxChange](https://github.com/vim-scripts/OnSyntaxChange). My first usage attempt is to enable text wrapping when editing Python comments and multi-line strings.

The first part was easy, as it's basically one of the documented examples:

```
autocmd Filetype python call OnSyntaxChange#Install('Comment', '^Comment$', 1, 'i')
autocmd Filetype python autocmd User SyntaxCommentEnterI setlocal textwidth=80
autocmd Filetype python autocmd User SyntaxCommentLeaveI setlocal textwidth=0
```

However, it doesn't seem like the built-in Python syntax file makes any distinction between multi-line and single-line Python comments.

I used [SyntaxAttr.vim](https://github.com/inkarkat/SyntaxAttr.vim) (props to [Ingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813602/ingo-karkat), he made both these plugins) to check the syntax group of strings in Python, and they all show:

```
group: pythonString->String
```

How do I solve this? Is there an alternative syntax file I can use? Or could I solve this with a minor modification to the built-in one?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's necessary to take a look at the source code. (so this might break later in future Vim versions
because it depends on specific `group-name` values in the original syntax file.)

From `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/python.vim`:

```
" Triple-quoted strings can contain doctests.
syn region  pythonString matchgroup=pythonQuotes
      \ start=+[uU]\=\z(['"]\)+ end="\z1" skip="\\\\\|\\\z1"
      \ contains=pythonEscape,@Spell
syn region  pythonString matchgroup=pythonTripleQuotes
      \ start=+[uU]\=\z('''\|"""\)+ end="\z1" keepend
      \ contains=pythonEscape,pythonSpaceError,pythonDoctest,@Spell
syn region  pythonRawString matchgroup=pythonQuotes
      \ start=+[uU]\=[rR]\z(['"]\)+ end="\z1" skip="\\\\\|\\\z1"
      \ contains=@Spell
syn region  pythonRawString matchgroup=pythonTripleQuotes
      \ start=+[uU]\=[rR]\z('''\|"""\)+ end="\z1" keepend
      \ contains=pythonSpaceError,pythonDoctest,@Spell


hi def link pythonString        String
hi def link pythonRawString     String
```

So we can add

```
syn region  pythonTripleQuotedString matchgroup=pythonTripleQuotes
      \ start=+[uU]\=\z('''\|"""\)+ end="\z1" keepend
      \ contains=pythonEscape,pythonSpaceError,pythonDoctest,@Spell
syn region  pythonRawTripleQuotedString matchgroup=pythonTripleQuotes
      \ start=+[uU]\=[rR]\z('''\|"""\)+ end="\z1" keepend
      \ contains=pythonSpaceError,pythonDoctest,@Spell
hi def link pythonTripleQuotedString        String
hi def link pythonRawTripleQuotedString     String
```

to `.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`.

Looks like everything works as expected.